# Working with SAPUI5 and SOAP request and response from web service

Tags: javascript, soap, xml-parsing, sapui5

My question is that I am working on a refactoring project that was made in flash and have to convert it to SAUI5 and to do that I have use a soap web service. It has multiple parts to the web service. Ajax call looks like this:

```
`var oAppSettings = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("appSettings").getData();
        var response;
        var oData;
        var oXMLModel = new sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel();

        var sReq = "<soapenv:Envelope 
        xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" 
        xmlns:web=\"http://webservice.cpb.dqw.sap.com\">\n" +
            "   <soapenv:Header/>\n" +
            "   <soapenv:Body>\n" +
            "      <web:boeLogonWithToken>\n" +
            "         <!--Optional:-->\n" +
            "         <web:args0>"+oAppSettings.loginToken+"</web:args0>\n" 
            +
            "      </web:boeLogonWithToken>\n" +
            "   </soapenv:Body>\n" +
            "</soapenv:Envelope>";

        $.ajax({
            url: oAppSettings.serverPath + ".AdminHttpSoap11Endpoint/",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: sReq,
            //processData:false,
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                response = data;
                console.log(response);
                console.log("Is a success!");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                console.log("Error: : " + status);
            },
            complete: function (xhr, status) {
                console.log(response);
                setUpData();
            }
        });

        function setUpData(){
            oXMLModel.setData(response);

            console.log(oXMLModel.getXML());
        }`
```

the response I get is this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:boeLogonWithTokenResponse 
         xmlns:ns="http://webservice.cpb.dqw.sap.com">
            <ns:return xmlns:ax22="http://shared.cpb.dqw.sap.com/xsd" 
             xmlns:ax21="http://types.cpb.dqw.sap.com/xsd" 
             xmlns:ax24="http://types.sdk.boe.dqw.sap.com/xsd" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:type="ax21:CPBAdminResult">
                <ax21:contentUpgradeVersion>0</ax21:contentUpgradeVersion>
                <ax21:cpInfo xsi:nil="true" />
                <ax21:errorData xsi:nil="true" />
                <ax21:intValue xsi:nil="true" />
                <ax21:projectInfo xsi:nil="true" />
                <ax21:reservedData xsi:nil="true" />
                <ax21:status>OK</ax21:status>
                <ax21:stringArray xsi:nil="true" />
                <ax21:stringValue xsi:nil="true" />
            </ns:return>
        </ns:boeLogonWithTokenResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`
```

I would like to know how to parse through the xml returned with the xml model of SAPUI5.

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking how to just parse the results? Wouldn't any XML parser be able to provide this?

Comment: I have been trying everything and when I try the simplest example of a parser it returns undefined. Tried this one not too long ago:  var parser, text, xmlDoc;

           parser = new DOMParser();

           xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/xml");
           console.log(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ns\\:return")[0].childNodes[6].nodeValue);

Comment: You should show what you have tried in the text of the question, along with any error messages. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use: (jQuery will be loaded already with SAPUI5)

```
var xmlContent =
    `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:boeLogonWithTokenResponse 
         xmlns:ns="http://webservice.cpb.dqw.sap.com">
            <ns:return xmlns:ax22="http://shared.cpb.dqw.sap.com/xsd" 
             xmlns:ax21="http://types.cpb.dqw.sap.com/xsd" 
             xmlns:ax24="http://types.sdk.boe.dqw.sap.com/xsd" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:type="ax21:CPBAdminResult">
                <ax21:contentUpgradeVersion>0</ax21:contentUpgradeVersion>
                <ax21:cpInfo xsi:nil="true" />
                <ax21:errorData xsi:nil="true" />
                <ax21:intValue xsi:nil="true" />
                <ax21:projectInfo xsi:nil="true" />
                <ax21:reservedData xsi:nil="true" />
                <ax21:status>OK</ax21:status>
                <ax21:stringArray xsi:nil="true" />
                <ax21:stringValue xsi:nil="true" />
            </ns:return>
        </ns:boeLogonWithTokenResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`;
var res = jQuery.parseXML(xmlContent)
var values = res.getElementsByTagName("ns:return")[0];
var result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < values.children.length; i++) {
    var key = values.children[i].nodeName.replace("ax21:", "");
    result[key] = values.children[i].innerHTML;
}
console.log(result);
```

Please note that this is bit crude way.

You can convert this into generic one.

My suggestion would be get JSON itself from the server instead of doing this circus on UI.

*Cheers!*

Comment: Thank you for this I will give it a try as I this is being done without changing the web service if at all possible.

Comment: On a side note if one of those tags have multiple values then would I add an extra loop to get each one at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seemed to want to know how to use the XMLModel (and you should have held out for that answer ;)) as it is simpler than it first appears and means you do not have to convert to JSON.

Create an instance of your XMLModel with the XML supplied in:

```
var oModel = new XMLModel();
oModel.loadData("response.xml");
```

Navigate to the element you want to get to:

```
var path = "/soapenv:Body/ns:boeLogonWithTokenResponse/ns:return";
oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function(){
        var status = oModel.getProperty(path + "/ax21:status"); 
});
```